# How to return a 404 HTML page in next.js when using the app router. route.js

Tags: next.js

In next.js 13 you can have dynamic api endpoints. I'm wondering though how one might return a 404 with HTML when doing this. I've tried using the notFound() function but I just get a blank screen.

//app/some-path/[slug]/route.ts

```
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'

export async function GET(request) {
  notFound()
}
```

Update:

So far the best solution I have been able to come up with is as follows:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export default async function notFound(origin) {
  const fetchRes = await fetch(origin + "/404")
  const html = await fetchRes.text()

  console.log(fetchRes.status, fetchRes.statusText);
  const response = new NextResponse(html, { 
    status: 404,
    statusText: "Not Found",
    headers: { "content-type": "text/html" } 
  });

  return response;
}
```

This seems a bit hackish to me so am going to keep this open in case someone knows a more orthodox way to do this.

Comment: How you are calling this endpoint?

Comment: It is in app/[slug]/route.ts and I am loading it from a web browser.